# Is it Possible to Create a Flutter App which has no Interface?

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity

I would like to know if it is possible to create a flutter app which has no interface and just runs in the background like a background Activity. If yes, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: This is more of an Android detail than Flutter. To run a background process you need an Android Service. To have your Android Service run without interruption by the OS, you need to ensure it's Foreground; for that you need an Icon/Context... you see where this is going. The answer is "not really" (intentionally). Best you can do is use WorkManager to schedule your background work when the conditions are met, but you still need to attach that work to "something".

Comment: ok thanks, i think i get your point

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what Martin Marconcini wrote in his comment: No this is not possible.

But why? Because if it would be possible it could be used for spyware, viruses and similar.